# How is it called a simple Java program with GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I made a simple Java program using a **JFrame**. I want to know how is it called or what type it is. Maybe is it an **API**? Maybe a **form**?
If a ask something about [my simple Java program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpwCI.png) 
[image]

in a forum, I would like to do it properly! I used **Eclipse**.

Comment: A **desktop application**.

Comment: It is a java application with a graphical user interface, nothing more fancy than that. In general, perhaps it could be called  a desktop application.

Comment: I would just call it a Java application.

Comment: It's a Java Swing application.

Comment: and API is an Application Programming Interface. Like how you're using Swing for your frame and components, Swing is part of the Java SE API

Comment: @robysottini I think the best place to start with Java and GUIs is [***The Swing Tutorial***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: It is a graphical user interface (GUI) that happens to be written in Java Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is unclear, so I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. But it seems like that would just be called a Java desktop application.